printing particular value from a nested dictionary-Python
I would like to print the descriptions of the friends whose last names are "Geller" from a nested dictionary:
friends={
    "Rachel":{
        "job":"fashion",
        "last name":"Green",
        "description":" brave for starting life over",
    },
    "Monica":{
        "job":"culinary",
        "last name":"Geller",
        "description":"likes things clean",
    },
    "Phoebe":{
        "job":"musician/masseuse",
        "last name":"Buffay",
        "description":"somewhat of a question mark",
    },
     "Chandler":{
        "job":"statistical analysis and data reconfiguration",
        "last name":"Bing",
        "description":"the funny one",
    },
     "Joey":{
        "job":"actor",
        "last name":"Tribbiani",
        "description":"italian american actor, born in queens, 7 sisters, only boy, NY Knicks rule",
    },
     "Ross":{
        "job":"dinosaurs",
        "last name":"Geller",
        "description":"3 divorces",
    },
}

so far i tried saving the results from the below loop into a variable but only managed to print the names
for i in friends:
    print(friends[i]["description"])

the loop prints all of the descriptions but i only need to print one description

You don't need a loop at all.  print(friends[name]["description"])

You only need save the friend name in a varible, for example:
friend_name = "Rachel"
Later, you can access to the description of Rachel in the dict, with this line:
description = friends[friend_name]["description"]

ok perhaps i should have worded it differently. what if i wanted to print the description of everyone whose last name is "Geller"? Im going to edit my original post

@Doll In this case, a way can be looped for all the elements of friends.
for name, info in friends.items(): Later you need to certificate if the last name is “Geller” with if info.get("last name") == "Geller": Now, you can print the description like  print(f"{name}: {info.get('description')}")

With a generator expression: print(*(x['description'] for x in friends.values() if x['last name'] == 'Geller'), sep='\n')

You can use a conditional to check whether or not the last name for that person is "Geller" like this:
for i in friends:
    if friends[i]['last name'] == 'Geller':
        print(friends[i]['description'])

This will print out the 'description' of all the friends whose last names are 'Geller'.
